# Abusing Java Arrays?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm developing a software package which makes heavy use of arrays (ArrayLists). Instructions to be process are put into an array queue to be processed, then when used, deleted from the array. Same with drawing on a plot, data is placed into an array queue, which is read to plot data, and the oldest data is eventually deleted as new data comes in. We are talking about thousands of instructions over an hour and at any time maybe 200,000 points plotted, continually growing/shrinking the array.

After sometime, the software beings to slow where the instructions are processed slower. Nothing really changes as to what is going on for processing, that is, the system is stable as to what how much data is plotted and what instructions are being process, just working off similar incoming data time after time.

Is there some memory issue going on with the "abuse" of the variable-sized (not a defined size, add/delete as needed) arrays/queues that could be causing eventual slowing?

Is there a better way than the String ArrayList to act as a queue?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the profiler say is the bottleneck?

Comment: (Also you might be looking for `Queue`)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to what you are referring? Could you point me in the right direction? Sounds useful. I'm using Eclipse if that helps.

Comment: You probably have a memory leak.  This is the perfect time to learn to use a profiler. Visualvm is a good starting point

Comment: as @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen suggested you should use any of the tools to check the profiler to check your memory usage, functions, and GC. Check the performance of Garbage Collector and pause time

Comment: Just as a doghouse is not a kind of dog, an ArrayList is not a kind of array, but a list (even though internally the implementation may use an array).

Comment: When you use an ArrayList, it will keep growing.  Deleting items from ArrayList is not going to change the size.  You should either use ArrayQueue or LinkedList.

Comment: I agree that a profiler is your best place to start. I would also set the initial capacity of the ArrayList to larger than you will ever need. Resizing is expensive with an ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are most likely using the wrong data structure for the job. An ArrayList is a list with a backing array so `get()` is fast.

The Java runtime library has a very rich set of data structures so you can get a well-written and debugged with the characteristics you need out of the box.  You most likely should be using one or more `Queue`s instead.

My guess is that you forget to null out values in your arraylist so the JVM has to keep all of them around.  This is a memory leak.

To confirm, use a profiler to see where your memory and cpu go. Visualvm is a nice standalone. Netbeans include one.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I was deliberately vague about which implementation for OP to actually think about which one suits the problem best.

Answer (score 0):

The use of VisualVM helped. It showed a heavy use of a "message" form that I was dumping incoming data to and forgot existed, so it was dealing with a million characters when the sluggishness became apparent, because I never limited its size.

Comment: Congratulations - you  are now a better programmer 